# VB.NET webrequest returning 404 when the url is correct

Tags: vb.net, webrequest

I have been at this for hours trying everything. I am porting this code from an Access 2010 project to vb.net  I have no idea what could be going wrong here.

Visual Studio 2019, Framework 4.7.2

```
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBody)
    url = "https://rest.avatax.com/api/v2/companies/" & OE2019HomeForm.strAvalaraCompany & "/certificates/"

    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(url)

    Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Method = "Post"
    request.Headers.Add("40", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & OE2019HomeForm.strAuth)
    request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    request.Headers.Add("20", "application/json") 'this is the accept header
    request.Headers.Add("12", "text/plain") ' content type
    request.ContentLength = data.Length
    



    Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    stream.Close()

    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using responsestream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(responsestream)
                Dim webresponse As String
                webresponse = reader.ReadToEnd()
                MsgBox(webresponse)


            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

' if I add line below before dimming the request I get "'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.' Inner Exception: Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

any help would be fantastic.

Comment: `request.ContentType = "application/json" request.UserAgent = "[A User Agent]" request.Accept = "application/json,*;q=0.8" request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " & [Your Token] request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")` etc. Don't try to pass strings as the Header enumeration, it's not a string. Set `Option Strict On` -- Nobody uses SSL3, it's deprecated. -- In what System have you tested this code? If Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, you may need to specify `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` before anything else.

Comment: Anyway, a 404 is a *not found* error, so you may want to check whether the API has changed something in the meanwhile. You should post the complete `url` string after it has been set in code (and verify its content while debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?
Put this near the top.

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3



    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(obj As [Object],
                                                       certificate As X509Certificate,
                                                       chain As X509Chain,
                                                       errors As SslPolicyErrors) (True)
```